# param is missing or the value is empty: item in ruby on rails on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I've looked stackoverflow questions regarding to this question(also followed all the instructions given). I am trying to add an new item but I am encountering this error..

[image: Output]

Question: Why I am getting this error? What is it?

**Controller**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
    def addItem

    end
    def create
      @item = Item.new(post_params)
      @item.save
      redirect_to @item
    end
    def show
        @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    end
    private
        def post_params
            params.require(:item).permit(:item, :description, :price)
        end
end
```

**Add Item view**

```
<%= form_for :post, url: items_create_path do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :Item %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :item %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :Description %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :description %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :Price %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :price %>

    </p>
    <p>
    <%= f.submit :Submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'BACK', items_path %>
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

            # URL           Controller#method
    get '/items/addItem' => 'items#addItem'
    get '/items/' => 'items#index'
    post '/items/create' => 'items#create'

end
```

**My Table**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170323165252) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

end
```

Comment: you should check the object that you passed in form_for. And see more in http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Comment: I will tell you what you are doing wrong show me your terminal

Comment: @RockwellRice sir, I tried to change form_for :post into form_for :item as you suggested. it gives me an error Extracted source (around line #8)end def create AT(symbol) item = Item.new(post_params) AT(symbol)item.save redirect_to AT(symbol)item end

Comment: Show your items table column in schema.rb file

Comment: Done sir,kindly check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `items` table does not have `item` field. You are using the name `item` for `name` field. So replace `item` with `name` and it should work.
**Controller**

```
params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :price)
```

**Add Item view**

```
<p>
    <%= f.label :Item %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
</p>
```

Comment: Ohh i thought it just the name of the field(similiar in PHP, name/id) Thanks man!